# Change grid background colour when ItemsControl is clicked

Tags: wpf, xaml, itemscontrol

I have the following `ItemsControl` in a `Grid`.

```
 <Grid Grid.Row="0">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
 <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="{StaticResource ControlBorder}" Background="{StaticResource ControlBackground}">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="2"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" Margin="1"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
 </Border>
```

I want to change the background of the grid cell whenever an item in the `ItemsControl` is clicked my the mouse.  How do I do this?

Comment: do you want to fill grid cell or entire grid since you are having only one grid row/Column?

Comment: Just the grid cell. There are several rows in this grid all with an items control.

Comment: see my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define `Grid` outside your `ContentControl` with `MouseLeftButtonDown` event
and if its Clicked change the background of your grid

**Xaml:**

```
 <Grid x:Name="MyGrid" Grid.Row="0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="{StaticResource ControlBorder}" Background="{StaticResource ControlBackground}">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="2"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid x:Name="GridInsideDataTemplate" VerticalAlignment="Top" MouseLeftButtonDown="Grid_MouseLeftButtonDown">
                            <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" Margin="10"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </Border>

    </Grid>
```

**Code:**

```
private void Grid_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    MyGrid.Background = Brushes.Green;
}
```

**Edited:**

Since you wish to do this entirely in XAML.

Use Event Trigger on MouseDown Event with KeyTime "0"

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid x:Name="GridInsideDataTemplate" VerticalAlignment="Top">
      <Grid.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Grid">
           <Setter Property="Background">
             <Setter.Value>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="Yellow"/>
             </Setter.Value>
           </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
           <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseDown">
               <BeginStoryboard>
                  <Storyboard>                                                    
                     <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Green" />                                                    
                     </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                   </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
              </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
          </Grid.Style>

         <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" Margin="10"/>

   </Grid>
 </DataTemplate>
```

**Alternatively** you can define style as a resource and use it for any Grid

```
<Grid x:Name="GridInsideDataTemplate"
      Style="{StaticResource GridStyle}"      
      VerticalAlignment="Top">

          <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" Margin="10"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Its only this cell that I want to change the background for. Row=0, Column=0 and not the whole grid. Apologies this is one cell.

Comment: try and let me know if it helps.

Comment: Yes this works thanks :)  Can this also be done totally in XAML? Without the need for a click handler? I will eventually have several grids and when they are clicked I want to change the background of each individual cell.

Comment: @HarryBoy see my Edited Answer

Answer (score 1):

You could handle the `MouseLeftButtonDown` event for the `ContentControl` in the `ItemTemplate`, find the parent `Border` in the visual tree and change the `Background` of this one:

```
private void ContentControl_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    ItemsControl ic = FindParent<ItemsControl>(sender as DependencyObject);
    if (ic != null)
    {
        Border border = ic.Parent as Border;
        if (border != null)
            border.Background = Brushes.Blue;
    }
}

private static T FindParent<T>(DependencyObject dependencyObject) where T : DependencyObject
{
    var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dependencyObject);
    if (parent == null)
        return null;

    var parentT = parent as T;
    return parentT ?? FindParent<T>(parent);
}
```

A "cell" is defined by the element in that particular position of the `Grid`, i.e. the `Border` element in this case.